# ASP.NET Show Div Conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have googled this and didn't find what I needed.  All of the existing solutions I found say to set "visibility" to false.  This will not seem to work for me as my application renders PDF which simply "hides" the DIV and leaves a big white space in it's place.

Instead, I would like to not render the HTML at all.  For instance, in PHP, this could be done as simply as:

```
<?php if ($showDiv == true) { ?>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<?php } ?>
```

In ASP.NET MVC, I could simply pass a ViewBag variable and do the same thing.

What is the solution for this in ASP.NET (C#)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<% if ( showDiv ) { %>
<div></div>
<% } %>
```

where showDiv would be a protected property in your code behind.

Comment: VB Solution : <% if ( showDiv ) then %>
<div></div>
<% End If %>

Answer (score 10):

In the aspx file

```
<div runat="server" id="hideableDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

And in the code behind

```
...
hideableDiv.Visible = false;
...
```

Comment: Sorry, Mat.  This is what I already tried to explain will not work for me.  It simply renders a big blank space in my PDF.  You see, it seems to simply set "display: none" whereas I don't want the element to be in the code at all.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @user1477388 It would be good of you to post the code for what you have tried.

Comment: @user1477388 Setting `Visible=false` wont render the element at all.

Comment: @Matt is correct here. I am not aware of anything that will render `display: none;` I do however think that using a server side `<asp:Panel>` control is more in character with asp.net. Both this and the solution I provided will work.

Comment: All solutions were helpful.  I think the issue I experience was caused by the DIV being inside of a `<tr>`.  Once I placed the conditional around the `<tr>` instead of just the DIV, the large space disappeared.  thanks for all your help, everyone,

Comment: @user1477388 You can have a `<tr>` runat=server also and set visibility.

Comment: Good call, magnus.  That may be a better solution for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

use a `<asp:panel>` control which renders as a HTML `<div>`. You can then toggle the visibility. If `visible` is set to false, asp.net will not render any content.

```
    <asp:Panel id="MyPanel" runat="server">
    ...
    </asp:Panel>

   MyPanel.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

The  markup

```
<div runat="server" id="myPdfDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

The codebehind

```
myPdfDiv.Visible = false;
myPdfDiv.InnerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can put the div inside an ASP PlaceHolder control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder(v=vs.71).aspx

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div></div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then in the codebehind you can set it like so:

```
PlaceHolder1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that would not produce any HTML:

**HTML**:

```
<asp:Literal ID ="litDiv" runat="server">       
</asp:Literal>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
bool showDiv = true;
if (showDiv)
    this.litDiv.Text = "<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>";
```